# Suggested META Tags?

Tags: html

I'm actually using HTML 5 and I would like to build a valid and secure code with it.

Can someone please tell me what are the requirements in meta tags?

I currently have the following:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Any more required / or suggested, because of the validity or security of the website?

Comment: FWIW, I think you mean `UTF-8`, not `UFT-8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check validity I would run your site against http://validator.w3.org/ and correct any errors it shows. Also testing against things like DOM Monster (http://mir.aculo.us/dom-monster/) and YSlow (http://yslow.org/) for common tweaks.